# How to chain multiple processors in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

How can I add a chain of processors to my Camel route, e.g.:

```
from("file:source?noop=true")
.process(new MyProcessor1()).to(
            "file:destination?fileName=output.csv");
```

Can add multiple processors sequentially to my route like this:

```
from("file:source?noop=true")
    .process(new MyProcessor1()).process(new Processor2()) .to(
            "file:destination?fileName=output.csv");
```

Alternatively, can I use a chained processor like this:

```
 DefaultMessageProcessorChainBuilder builder=new DefaultMessageProcessorChainBuilder();
builder.chain(new TestMessageProcessor("1"),
  new TestMessageProcessor("2"),
  new TestMessageProcessor("3"));
MessageProcessor mpChain=builder.build();
```

Any thoughts on how we can achieve the same with Camel?

Answer (score 3):

a Camel route defines the [chain of processors](http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html) using from() and to()...

[image]

an Exchange is created when the route is invoked and each processor in a route can decorate it along the way...

from(endpoint).to(step1).to(step2)...